# i want to execute javascript on pageunload if var is true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

the goal of this script is to only execute on page close when edited (a bool in ASP)  is true

here is what the code looks like....

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (){
     if (<%=edited%>){  
         return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';  }

      };
```

how would i get this to work?

Comment: How about using [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9(v=vs.110).aspx) in code behind?

Comment: Similar post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192343/how-do-i-tell-the-web-browser-that-the-user-has-modified-the-page/21192811#21192811